# jQuery - indefinitely scroll and loop one image inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, image, scroll

I'd like to create an auto-scrollable image inside of a div. like, I have a picture that's 600px wide and 1200px tall and I'd like to display it inside a 600px by 200px div and make it scroll and loop indefinitely. the jQuery plugins I've tried are all designed to scroll multiple li items, and I've failed hard at adapting it to my needs. so I tried chopping up the image into multiple pieces but that just looks horrid. any pointers?

```
<style type="text/css">
  #autoscroll {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
...
<div id="autoscroll">
  <img src="someimage.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setup a container with `overflow` set to `hidden` and the dimensions you want to display. Then add your image as a child of this container and animate its position:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="src_of/img.jpg" width="600" height="1200" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position : relative;
    width    : 600px;
    height   : 200px;
    overflow : hidden;
}

#container > img {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var $image = $('#container').children('img');
    function animate_img() {
        if ($image.css('top') == '0px') {
            $image.animate({top: '-1000px'}, 2500, function () {
                animate_img();
            });
        } else {
            $image.animate({top: '0px'}, 2500, function () {
                animate_img();
            });
        }
    }
    animate_img();
});
```

Note that I animate the `top` of the image to the negative of the height of the image minus the height of container ((container.height() - image.height()) * -1).

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/J9BM8/1/

Comment: thank you for your speedy reply. how do I make it loop always in the same direction? so it don't go back to the top in reverse but loops it from the beginning when it reaches the end?

Comment: got it... added $image.css('top','0px'); before animate_img(); in the first complete function. thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that you can also animate the image in "three" dimensions. I've made something very close to the code above that scrolled in two dimensions and when it hit certain spots it changed the height/width of the image to simulate zooming-in.

Answer (score 2):

an update to @jasper's answer.

scroll time is adjustable as image height & also top scroll. Top and Scroll time are dynamic
    http://jsfiddle.net/J9BM8/476/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<img src="https://d98b8t1nnulk5.cloudfront.net/production/images/layout/devices/default/ios_iPhone-5S_7.0_portrait.jpg?1445944951" width="320" />
```

JS

```
$(function () {
var $image = $('#container').children('img');
function animate_img() {
    if ($image.css('top') == '0px') {
        $image.animate({top: -($image.height()-468)+"px"}, $image.height()*5, function () {
            animate_img();
        });
    } else {
        $image.animate({top: '0px'}, $image.height()*5, function () {
            animate_img();
        });
    }
}
animate_img();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a repeated background like

```
 #autoscroll {
   background-image: url('someimage.jpg');
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
 }
```

and animate the background position.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the image as the background of the div (instead of using the img tag and putting the image inside the div) and then animating the background coordinates of the image using jQuery through the `background-position` css property.

I don't have any code but this souldn't be hard to implement and it should work.

Comment: It could be incorrect semantically and bad for accessibility. It depends on its content though.